# CSS not load Magento 2

Tags: magento2, static-content

I installed a module, and then I uninstalled it.

Since then I do not have CSS. I did not find the frontend nor the CSS but after running this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Make sure apache `rewrite_module` is enable and then restart the server

Delete cache folder under `var/cache`

The backend CSS is back but the frontend is still unloaded.

For theme luma it's works but this is the error with my theme:

[image]

How can I load it?

Thank you

Comment: flush cache and delete folder view_preprocessed from var

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It not working, I probe but not.

Comment: What do you see in console?

Answer (score 4):

What kind of language are you using? `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` only deploys `en_US`

Note that `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` has to be language specific. For example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL
```

Comment: For theme luma this has worked, but in a post category a my theme that previously worked perfectly and without any modification after uninstalling the module that I said before, gives me the error in description edit